# Python Homework MPG sample

Tags: python

Sample Run

```
Enter gallons used (-1 to quit): 12
Enter miles driven: 285
MPG: 23.75

Enter gallons used (-1 to quit): 13
Enter miles driven: 292
MPG: 22.46

Enter gallons used (-1 to quit): 10.3
Enter miles driven: 202.6
MPG: 19.67

Enter gallons used (-1 to quit): -1

Average MPG: 22.08
```

Below is my code, it works yet I keep only getting .08 for average mpg. Any advice would help, thank you.

```py
total_mpg = 0
total_miles = 0

while True:
  gallon = float(input("Enter gallons used (-1 to quit): "))

  if gallon ==-1:
    break
  else:
    miles = float(input("Enter miles driven: "))
    mpg=miles/gallon

    print("MPG: {:0.2f}\n".format(mpg))

    total_mpg = mpg+total_mpg
    total_miles = miles+total_miles

averagempg = (total_mpg)/(total_miles)
print("Average MPG:", round(averagempg,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
averagempg = (total_mpg)/(total_miles)
```

Miles per gallon per mile? That is in no way (constant-) proportional to miles per gallon<sup>(a)</sup>.

I suspect you want one of the following two possibilities:

- total miles divided by total gallons:
  `(285 + 292 + 202.6) / (12 + 13 + 10.3)`
  `= 779.6 / 35.3`
  `= 22.08 mpg`; or
- total miles per gallon divided by number of entries (loop iterations):
  `(23.75 + 22.46 + 19.67) / 3`
  `= 65.88 / 3`
  `= 21.96`.

Given your sample run, it looks like you should be using the first option.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If there was *one* thing my high school physics teacher said to remember from his classes, it's to always check the units of the result. If you're looking for (as an example) a speed, your result should *not* be in kilograms per watt :-)